# Sortable DIV columns

Tags: jquery, sorting

I've been breaking my head over this one for a while..

I have a table with data which I'd like to make sortable using jQuery/Javascript. However, the table consists of CSS and is not and actual html table.

I've tried Tinysort & datatables.net, but they don't fit my specific usecase.

Example of the columns I try to sort:

```
<div class="row clan_header_row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Name</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><strong>Networth</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><strong>Land</strong></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

See all @ https://jsfiddle.net/ehf7atpv/

Basically what I'm trying to achieve, is making the columns land, networth & name sortable.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why not just use a table (in which case the plugins you've mentioned will work). This looks like data that does belong in a table.

Comment: Tables are generally horrible on mobile. This stacks a lot nicer :)